# Two types of markers in Google Maps using MarkerClusterer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have two kinds of geolocation informations: one is the exact location, the other is an aproximated, region level geolocation. As I show these informations on a map, I would like to be able to use a different marker type for each kind of location, the exact location would be green and the approximated location would be blue.
I'm using the MarkerClusterer to group Markers into one bubble, but, I need two MarkerClusterers, one for approximated locations, another for exact locations. Doing so, my MarkerCluster is one for each kind of geolocation.

My problem is: sometimes, the two Clusters overlaps, wich may lead into confusion:

[image: Image with low zoom]

As you can see, it shows that I have 7 markers there (here's it blue, but it's really a green Marker, as these geolocations are the exact kind).

[image: Zoomed in image]

But, zooming in, I have 9, because the second Cluster was underneath the first one (note that for now booth Clusters has the same color, it was supposed to be green (7) and blue (2) - so the user can be sure that the (2) locations are approximated)

Any ideas on how can I make a Cluster of Clusters? Or another approach to let the user know that there are two kinds of information?

Answer (score 5):

If you have only two (or a few) classes of marker, then one approach is to create a second MarkerClusterer instance.  So lets have two sets of options where the styles (not shown) are different:

```
var mcOptions1 = {gridSize: 40, styles: clusterStyles1, maxZoom: 19};       
var mcOptions2 = {gridSize: 40, styles: clusterStyles2, maxZoom: 19 };
```

Then you can build two separate arrays of markers, say markers1 and markers2, which in my case depend on a *status* attribute of the marker:
(note that every marker is added to the map also as normal, not shown)

```
// push to the array, markers[]
    switch(status)
    {
    case 'Include':
        markers1.push(marker);
      break;
    case 'Exclude':
        markers2.push(marker);
      break;
    default:
        markers1.push(marker);
    };
```

Finally, then create the two MarkerClusterer instances each with separate arrays and options

```
var markerClust1 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers1, mcOptions1);
var markerClust2 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers2, mcOptions2);
```

The result on the map shows two styles of marker icons and two styles of Clusters.  As you zoom out the two separate markers never get clustered together - I think this is just what you need, and it looks good on the map!
(I'd like to post some map pics, but cannot post images until my reputation increases!!)

I did use the later [MasterClusterPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) rather than the earlierr MasterClusterer, but I cannot see any reason that the approach will not work with the earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

I am dealing with this problem right now.
You can use what [qurn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221722/qurm) said, and change clustermarker style, so the icons won't overlap.

```
        var clusterStyles = [
        {   
            url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/conv30.png',
            height: 27,
            width: 30,
            anchor: [3, 0],
            textColor: '#11ffbb',
            textSize: 10,
            offsetX: 20,
            offsetY: 20
          }, {
            url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/conv40.png',
            height: 36,
            width: 40,
            anchor: [6, 0],
            textColor: '#ff0000',
            textSize: 11,
            offsetX: 20,
            offsetY: 20
          }, {
            url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/conv50.png',
            width: 50,
            height: 45,
            anchor: [8, 0],
            textSize: 12,
            offsetX: 20,
            offsetY: 20
          }
        ];

        var mcOptions = {
            styles: clusterStyles
        };

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Then set "offsetX" and "offsetY" properties. 
Ex: If you have 4 categories / groups you can use offset: -20,-20 | -20,20 | 20, -20 | 20,20 
The goal is to get the icons around your point.

In case this won't help you, take a look at [Google Maps Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier).

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this issue with this

```
function addRandomOffset(latlng) {
                    const randomOffset = Math.random() * 0.0011; // Adjust the value as needed
                    return new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat() + randomOffset, latlng.lng() + randomOffset);
                }
                // Calculate a single random offset
                const randomOffset = Math.random() * 0.0011; // Adjust the value as needed
```

and add this function as position in google.maps.Marker